# android textview animation not smooth

Tags: android, animation, android-layout, textview

I am trying to perform 2 text animations in a row with my TextView under Android

first:

```
TextView target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textanimation);
target.setText(text1);
target.startAnimation(animationSet1);
```

animationSet1 is a set of alpha and translate animations:

```
Animation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);     
Animation a = new TranslateAnimation(
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,  0,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f, 
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);     

alpha.setDuration( 1000 );
a.setDuration( 1000 );
```

When onAnimationEnd happens in animationSet1 I immediately start another animation

```
TextView target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textanimation);
target.setText(text2);
target.startAnimation(animationSet1);
```

However in the 2nd animation I can see on a split of second a fully opaque text, however it should start with 0 alpha. How to avoid this situation? Will appresiate any answer.

P.S. Even if I have 2 separate textviews with the prepared text in both - same bug is seen.

If I put some delay between the animations both of them become smooth.

- Sergey

Comment: Its not clear at all what the problem you are experiencing is. Do you want the animated changes to stick after the animation finishes?

Comment: When first animation is compete (getAnimation is null) I remove previous text and assign new one and start new animation with the new text. I don't understand why in the very beggining of the second animation I see the text from the first one. Same problem even TexViews are different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are triggering the start of the 2nd animation following the termination of the 1st animation. I'm guessing you're checking to see if the animation on a view is null. This isn't the best or correct way to do it.  Instead you should you an `AnimationListener`

```
Animation animation1 = new Animation();//Replace with your animation

animation1.setDuration(DURATION_1);
animation1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {}
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        Animation animation2 = new Animation();
        animation2.setDuration(DURATION_2);
        view2.startAnimation(animation2);
    }
});

view1.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Comment: Thanks stayton. I am doing it exactly like you have post. In view2 text which should start with alpha 0 in the beggining on a split of second is fully opaque. I have declared my animation set in xml and inflate animation instead of preparing it programmaticaly and now it looks smoother, but not on all the devices.

Comment: does the first animation change the alpha to 0? does the split second of opaque occur in between the two animations?

Comment: Right, both animations are the same. They are a set of alpha (0 to 1) + translation simulteneous animations. opaque text occur in the begginig of the second animation and other part of the 2nd animation (as in my point of view) is happening yanked, i.e. jumps on some position upon translate animation direction in non-linear manner. I feel like it's trying to make up time which has been loosed on opaque text showing.

Comment: I believe it's urgent to say here, that animation is shown above GLSurfaceView where opengl scene is being rendered.

Comment: What happens if you perform a similar animation without the GLSurfaceView

Comment: Then you're probably running into performance limits on your device